# ionic footer hidden beneath keyboard

Tags: ionic2

I have a messaging page, having ion-footer at the bottom. Footer have an ion-textarea and a SEND button inside.

When we focus inside textarea, the keyboard comes up hiding the footer beneath. We want the footer to move along the keyboard and appear above the keyboard.

Also when we click the SEND button, the keyboard is dismissed. Whereas we want the keyboard to remain.

Attaching a screenshot of the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIvCx.png)

Expected behaviour is also attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bl07.png)

System information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0

Ionic Framework Version: **3.0.1**

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1

Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4

Node Version: v6.9.1

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?